# How can I get the active tabPanel on submit with TinyMCE dialogs?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I am testing out TinyMCE multi-tab dialogs using the documentation here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/dialog/. I can switch between tabs just fine, and submit from any of the tabs, but is there a way to get the active tab at the time of submit?

I am able to access the data from the active tab on submit, but nothing in the documentation shows how to detect what tab was open when the form was submitted (unless I missed something). Link to working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/byoung2/05ntx1ro/3/

```
onSubmit: function(api) {
  var data = api.getData();
  //Can I access the active tab here?

  tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, `
                <span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization"><a itemprop="url" href="${ data.url }"><strong itemprop="name">${ data.name }</strong></a></p>
  `);
  api.close();
}
```

Is there a method I can use in the submit handler that will tell me the name of the tab that was submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way, but this works

```
onTabChange: (dialogApi, details) => {
  currentTab = details.newTabName;
  console.log('changed',details.newTabName)
}
```

I'll just watch this and set a variable